# Shared Contact API - Error code 409 (Conflict) while deleting an contact

Tags: php, gmail-api, google-client

I am using google client for PHP I downloaded from here : https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/downloads/detail?name=google-api-php-client-0.6.7.tar.gz&can=1&q=

I am getting response code 409 - Conflict while trying to delete a contact. Please check my code here : http://staging.point-star.com/sharedcontact/code1/examples/contacts/shared_contact_api_del_code.png

Here is result screenshot : http://staging.point-star.com/sharedcontact/code1/examples/contacts/shared_contact_api_result_screenshot.png

It returns me detail of that contact in response body. What I am missing here ?

Comment: post your code here instead of linking to screenshots.

Comment: And please don't use short URLs.

Comment: 409 error is thrown generally when API request cannot be completed because the requested operation would conflict with an existing item or specified version number dosen't match with resources latest version number. https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/1.0/reference and https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-search/v2/standard-error-responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, I figure it out.. I was passing extra "/delete" at end of the URL. I just need to pass "https://google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/domain.com/full/xxx/xxx"  (I was passing xxx/xxx/delete").